# Update Fragment edit field based on the inputs from javascript interface dynamically

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have webview content which will send data that needs to be updated in fragment. I have written a javscript listener class and Im able to get the values from webview. But im not able to update those updated values in to fragment every time a change happens in webview. 
The fragment displays the initial default values when it is launched along with my activity(*which contains a fragment & a webview*). But after the application is launched then whenever I try to change the edit fields in fragment through my javscript listener class it throws null pointer exception. I even tried to update the same via Main activity object, but still failed saying null pointer exception.

**Main Activty.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        System.out.println("Inside MainActivity onCreate...");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ui_controlFragment = (UIControlFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.ui_control_fragment);
}
        if (ui_controlFragment != null) {//here the condition passes
            System.out.println("ui_controlFragment Not NULL.................");
        }
  }

public void updateUI2(double lat,double lng){
        System.out.println("Inside main activity updateUI2()");
        ui_controlFragment = (UIControlFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.ui_control_fragment);
        if (ui_controlFragment != null) {//here the condition fails. if i comment this condition it throws null pointer exception.

            System.out.println("Inside updateUI2, ui_controlFragment is not null");
            ui_controlFragment.updateUI(lat,lng);
        }
    }
}
```

**UIControlFragment.java**

```
public class UIControlFragment extends Fragment {
Activity mActivity;
View rootView;
EditText editLat;
EditText editLng;
public double latitude=35.0;
public double longitude=139.0;

    @Override
    public void onAttach (Activity activity){
        super.onAttach(activity);
        System.out.println("Inside onAttach UIControlFragment...");
        mActivity = activity;
    }
      @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        System.out.println("Inside onCreate UIControlFragment...");
        editLat =  new EditText(mActivity.getApplicationContext());
        editLng =  new EditText(mActivity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle bundle){
        System.out.println("Inside onCreateView UIControlFragment");
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = mActivity.getLayoutInflater();
        rootView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.control_ui, viewGroup, false);

        editLat = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editLat);
        editLat.setText("");
        editLng = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editLng);
        editLng.setText("");
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        System.out.println("Inside onResume UIControlFragment......");
        updateUI(latitude,longitude);//here it works because values are set during initial fragment launching.
    }

    public void updateUI(double lat,double lng){
        System.out.println("--------Inside updateUI UIControlFragment..lat: "+lat);
        editLat.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
        editLng.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
    }
}
```

**JSListener.java** //This is where the webview calls the javascript methods. Im myc ase UpdateView() method

```
public class JSListener{

UIControlFragment uiControlFragment;
MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();

@JavascriptInterface
    public void UpdateView(double lat,double lng){
        System.out.println("lat:"+lat+", lng:"+lng);
       try{
          mainActivity.updateUI2(lat,lng); //here im calling the updateUI method written inside MainActivity.java
       /*
       I also tried the below code, but that too didnt work as it too gave null value for uicontrolfragment object.
      uiControlFragment.updateUI(lat,lng); 
       */

       }catch(NullPointerException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

   }
}
```

What I have noticed is fragments once launched with values then cannot be updated in between. Like in my case I have lat,lng values coming whenever a change occurs in webview. How to update edit fields in fragments, after its initial launch.

Answer (score 0):

OKay I was able to resolve the issue.
The problem was I was having multiple instance of UICOntrol & MainActivity class.
I maintained one object of the same and used the same for all future UI edit field changes. 
Also I came across an error like UI should be changed via UI thread only. I resolved the same by executing the UI changes in UI thread as shown below:

```
getMainActivityObj().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        uiControlFragment.editLat.setText(String.valueOf(latitude));
                        uiControlFragment.editLng.setText(String.valueOf(longitude));
                    }
                });
```